# No me crea bien el nombre de usuario cuando envío petición con postman

Tags: nodejs, mongoose, postman

No entiendo porque el nombre de usuario que creo cuando envío petición con postman me da esto, el nombre sale así "ailyn\n" no entiendo porque la \n:

```
{
    "_id": "5adefce3c4892c0fa1a5078a",
    "nombre": "ailyn\n",
    "edad": 282,
    "raza": "caucasico",
    "puntosVida": 100,
    "ataque": 30,
    "playerNumber": "ninguno",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Parte del código:

```
var User = require("../models/User");
var Weapon = require('../models/Weapon');
var weaponCount = require('./weapon');
var turno = 0; // player 1 turn

//CREATE USERS
function createUser(req, res){
  nombre = req.body.nombre;
  edad = req.body.edad;
  raza = req.body.raza;
  puntosVida = req.body.puntosVida;
  ataque = req.body.ataque;
  playerNumber = 'ninguno';

    var user = new User({
      nombre:nombre,
      edad:edad,
      raza:raza,
      puntosVida: puntosVida,
      ataque:ataque,
      playerNumber: playerNumber,
    });

    user.save(function(err, user_new) {
      if(err){
        res.status(500).send({message:err.message});
        res.status(500).send(user.nombre.toUpperCase() + ' ya ha sido creado, pruba otro nombre diferente');
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(user_new);        
      }
    });
  }

//FIND USERS
function findAvailableUsers(req,res){
  User.find({},function(err, users){
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({message:err.message});
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(users);
    }
  });
}

//GIVE WEAPON TO USERS =>
function giveWeaponToUser(req,res){

  var userName = req.body.nombre;  
  var weaponName = req.body.arma;
  var count = 0;


  //counting remaining weapons
  Weapon.find({"nombre": weaponName},function (err, weaponName){
    for (var i = 0; i < weaponName.length; i++) {
      if (weaponName[i].available === true) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  });

  //find weapons which match the body query and the boolean true to convert to false
  Weapon.findOneAndUpdate({"nombre":weaponName, "available": true},{$set:{"available":false}}, function(err, weapon){
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({message:err.message});
    } else if(weapon === null){
      res.status(500).send("NO " + weaponName.toUpperCase() + 'S' + " AVAILABLE IN STOCK OR TYPED WRONG (We have pistola, cuchillo, escopeta, bazooka)");
    } else {
      //assign weapon to user selected
      User.findOneAndUpdate({"nombre":userName}, {$set:{"arma":weapon._id}}, function(err, user){

        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({message:err.message});
        } else if(user === null){ // no name found          
          res.status(500).send("NO NAME FOUND: " + userName.toUpperCase() + ", Create it first!");
          console.log(user);

        } else if(user.armaId !== 'ningunId'){ //reasign another weapon message
          res.status(500).send(userName + ' changed the weapon and now have: ' + weaponName.toUpperCase() + ' with ID: ' + weapon._id +  '\n Remaining ' + weaponName.toUpperCase() + 'S: ' +  count);
        } else { //give first weapon if doesnt have
          res.status(200).send('Weapon ' + "(" + weaponName.toUpperCase() + ")" + ' with ID: ' + weapon._id + ' has been assigned to ' + userName  +  '\n Remaining ' + weaponName.toUpperCase() + 'S: ' + count);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

function findUser(req,res){

  User.find({"_id":req.params.id}, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      res.status(500).send({message:err.message});
    } else{
      res.status(200).send(user);
    }
  });
}

//FIND USER WITH OBJECT ID
function findUserWithWeaponObj(req, res){

  User.find({"_id":req.params.id})
  .populate({path: 'arma'})// LE PASO EL OBJECTiD Y DESPLIEGO EL OBJETO DEL ARMA
  .exec(function(err, user){
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({message:err.message});
    } else{
      res.status(200).send(user);
    }
  });
}

//ATTACK
function attack(req,res){
  var player1 = req.body.ataca;
  var player2 = req.body.atacado;

  User.find({$or:[{"nombre": player1}, {"nombre":player2}]}, function(err, user){
    var jugador1 = user[0];//FRAN
    var jugador2 = user[1];//AILYN


    if (user[0] === undefined || user[1] === undefined) {
      res.status(500).send('No user mactch our DB, create it before play');
    } else {

      if (turno === 0) {//TURNO PRIMERO(FRAN)
        let vidaRestante = jugador2.puntosVida - jugador1.arma.dano;

        if (jugador2.puntosVida <= 0) {
          res.status(200).send(jugador2.nombre + ' HA PERDIDO');
        } else {
          User.updateOne({"nombre":player2},{$set:{"playerNumber":"player2", "puntosVida":vidaRestante}}, function(err, jugador1){
            // res.status(200).send('TURNO DE: ' + player1 +  ' (' + turno + ')' + '\n' + jugador1);
            res.status(200).send('TURNO DE: ' + player1 + ', vida restante: ' + vidaRestante);
            turno = 1;
          });
        }

      }else {//TURNO SEGUNDO(AILYN)
        let vidaRestante = jugador1.puntosVida - jugador2.arma.dano;

        if (jugador1.puntosVida <= 0) {
          res.status(200).send(jugador1.nombre + ' HA PERDIDO');
        }else {
          User.updateOne({"nombre":player1},{$set:{"playerNumber":"player1", "puntosVida":vidaRestante}}, function(err, jugador2){
            // res.status(200).send('TURNO DE: ' + player2 +  ' (' + turno + ')' + '\n' + jugador2);
            res.status(200).send('TURNO DE: ' + player2 + ', vida restante: ' + vidaRestante);
            turno = 0;
          });
        }

      }
    }
  });
}

//INSERT IMAGE
function insertImage(req,res){

  var imagePath = req.files.image.path;//image is my field to fill in the body
  var userId    = req.params.id;

  User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:userId}, {imagen:imagePath}, function(err, user){//image(ver mi model)
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({message:err.message});
    } else{
      res.status(200).send('Image: ' + imagePath + ' attached to user: ' + user.nombre);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: seguro? mira que lo que has puesto (el json de post) tiene precisamente \n... no sera que no lo quieres poner? Simplemente quitalo del valor de nombre...

Comment: exacto, no quiero \n y no se pq me sale

Comment: a lo que me refiero es que en el propio json que has puesto, viene ya con el \n. con que lo quites es suficiente.

Comment: yo me refiero a que eso es lo que me devuelve postman, no puedo quitarlo pq no se de donde sale me explico? es simplemente lo que me devuelve, algo que no deberia

Comment: en postman en req.body le paso ailyn y me devuelve ailn \n  eso es lo que digo

Comment: podrías probar enviando la respuesta como json `res.json(user_new)`. Y posiblemente aplicando un trim al parámetro del body que recibes. Puedes mostrarnos el body que envías mediante postman? Estás usando el header `Content-Type` con `application/json` ?

Comment: entendido el asunto. Por favor, cambia en la pregunta el texto para que se distinga QUE envias a Postman y QUE recibes. revisa como te dice @amenadiel los headers. Puedes añadir tambien el models User por favor?

Comment: esty usando el header content tipe para comprobar con el middleware que el usuario esta logeado, pero para crearlo no, uso x-www-url-encoded en el body   name: ailyn surname: manrique email: kmds@gmail.com rol: rol1  password: password1

Comment: revisa en la bbdd (o donde lo almacenes) si el valor se ha guardado con  \n. Si es asi, sabes que es en el proceso de guardado. Sino, sera que cuando lo lees se incluye de alguna manera.